# How to loop through a shrinking array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, array-splice

Suppose I have an array like this:

```
myArray = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
```

And I want to loop through it to find specific values and remove them.

```
for(var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
    if(myArray[i] == "b")
        myArray.splice(i,1)
}
```

the problem being, splice removes the item from the array, and all the items in front of the removed one, shift down an index number, so `myArray.length` was instantiated as 5 but after the `splice` `myArray` has a length of only 4 and the `for` loop fails since `myArray[4]` throws typeof match error in the framework.

I'm using a framework that works this way, that's why I'm utilizing such an item removal technique, my question is how to go about doing this the right way? The framework uses the `splice` method, I'm using the `for` loop, so I assume there's a correct way to go about this?

Comment: i not quite understand, what you mean here: `myArray[4] throws undefined error`

Comment: Save yourself the trouble and use` Array.map` or create a new array.

Comment: @Saravana, in this case better _filter_ :-)

Comment: @Grundy sorry about that, it's an error thrown in the framework because it's expecting a typeof to match, it's not an undefined error, i'll remove that bit

Comment: Just replace from `myArray.splice(i,1);` to `myArray.splice(i++,1);`. Then your code will work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reverse the loop:

```
for(var i=myArray.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    if(myArray[i] == "b")
        myArray.splice(i,1)
}
```

Comment: Came here to say this :) I write the `for` statement like this: `for(var i = myArray.length; i--;)`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I figured I was missing a simple algorithm change like this, really appreciate the quick help!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to determine which elements you want. For instance:

```
var myArray = ["a","b","c","d","e"];
var myNewArray = myArray.filter(function(elem) { return elem !== "b"; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function:

```
var myArray = ["a","b","c","d","e"];
myArray.filter(function(item) {
    return item !== "b";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you must use `splice`, then you could increment `i` in the loop and simply not increment it if the item is removed:

```
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length;) {
  if(myArray[i] == "b") {
    myArray.splice(i, 1);
  } else {
    ++i;
  }
}
```

Comment: technically this works too but the reverse way is cleaner, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Just replace from `i` to `i++` in your`myArray.splice(i,1)`

```
for(var i = 0; myArray[i]; i++){
    if(myArray[i] == "b")
        myArray.splice(i++,1)
}
```